# Convert println to format in arraylist in java

Tags: java

How to convert `println` to format tnx?

```
 int[] number = new int[5];

 for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("enter number :");
     number[i]=input.nextInt();
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("number ["+i+"]=" + number[i]+"");
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean with "tnx"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want to turn the `println` in your second `for` loop into a `printf` call, you could use `%d` to specify the `int` values and the new line with `%n`. Like,

```
System.out.printf("number [%d]=%d%n", i, number[i]);
```

Comment: tnx printf can be replace whit format like this:System.out.format("number [%d]=%d\n" ,i,number[i]);

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
System.out.println("number ["+i+"]=" + number[i]+"");
```

could be formatted like this:

```
String formattedOutput = String.format("number [%d]=%d",i, number[i]);
System.out.println(formattedOutput);
```